# Delphi: Como verificar se elemento obtido por getElementById realmente existe?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, navegador-de-internet

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```delphi
procedure TMainForm.ValidarAcesso;
var
  doc: variant;
  element: variant;
begin
  doc := coHTMLDocument.Create as IHTMLDocument2;
  doc.write(memHtml.Text);
  try
    element := doc.getElementById('theElementId');
    if VarToStr(element) <> '' then
      ShowMessage(element.innerText)
    else
      ShowMessage('Acesso realizado com sucesso!');
  except
  end;
end;
```

Crio um COM HTML Document e carrego o fonte Html de uma página nele e então procuro por um elemento html usando getElementById.
Isso Funciona!

**Mas, como faço para adicionar um controle para ver se o elemento realmente existe/foi encontrado na página/html?**

Quando o elemento não é encontrado, ao passar o mouse por cima da variável element, o Delphi mostra o valor `$00000000`.

Já testei:

```
VarToStr(element) <> ''
element <> $00000000
VarType(element) ...
element <> null
element <> nil
```

Mas nenhum deles funcionou!

Comment: Em javascript(no caso do WebView) uma variável nula é `undefined`, tente isso ou o `null` do Delphi, acho que é `Nil` né? (Obs: Não conheço praticamente nada de Delphi. só estou tentando ajudar)

Comment: Ok. É que como se tratava de uma nova tag acreditei que você tinha se enganado, pois eu todas as linguagens que eu conheço, o componente de Web é chamado de WebView. Bom saber que resolveu seu problema.

Comment: Já testou o método `assigned`?

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo encontrado na web e que funcionou:

```delphi
if Assigned(TVarData(element).VPointer) then
  ShowMessage(element.innerText)
else
  ShowMessage('Acesso realizado com sucesso!');
```